# what base SDK level should I use?

Tags: sdk, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I have apps listed on app store. Some of them are OS 10.6 compatiable.

Now, I want the user of OS 10.8 getting benifit from the new API of NSUserNotification and still want to serve the user under OS 10.6 and OS 10.7 with basic functions. What base SDK should I use on project setting while producing my new upgrades?

Or, should I use different targets?

Thank you for your basic tutorials. I really don't know and never used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Base SDK:    10.8
- Mac OS X Deployment Target:      10.6
- Build Active Architecture Only:  NO

these should be the solution.

Comment: I actually have an application that compiles just fine under 10.6 base but doesn't work with base 10.8, regardless of deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer to my question:

set "Base SDK" to the higest with the new APIs, here of cause 10.8
and
set "OS X Deployment Target" to the lowest system version you want to support, here of cause 10.6

Someone please confirm this.