# How to make an app use Growl on Lion and Notification Center on Mountain Lion?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, growl, nsusernotification

I am making an app that uses notification center on mountain lion. I included support for growl on snow leopard and lion. How do I make it so the binary will be able to run on both and not require 2 separate .app bundles.

Comment: Cannot you just test if Notification Center is available, and act accordingly?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my SDK settings, the app says it requires 10.8 before it even launches

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736877/how-to-build-an-app-that-runs-on-mac-os-10-6-and-supports-the-nsusernotification

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed. If you put it as an answer I can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would be building an app against the Growl framework and 10.7, and then have code to check at startup if Notification Center is available (which it will be on 10.8+) and use that instead. There is a very similar question about the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736877/how-to-build-an-app-that-runs-on-mac-os-10-6-and-supports-the-nsusernotification).